# Ask if user want to add another product (up selling ?)

Tags: magento2, product, cart, catalog, upselling

I have two issues :

1. I need my user to add one product (1) on his cart. Then, when this product is added, I want to ask if the user wants to add another product (2)
2. The product (2) is available only if the product (1) is in the cart.

How to I do that ?

Comment: You will ask user to add 2nd product on adding any 1st product to cart? or there will be some product if user add only those  then only you will ask to add 2nd product?

Comment: I will ask user to add 2nd product on adding any 1st product to cart

Comment: In my knowledge you can archive by showing popup to user once a product added to cart what we can do here is we have to check add to cart functionality we know that once product is being added to cart the page get refreshed so you need to call you custom function after that redirection which will show an popup to user for adding another product to cart.